# Limit of an definite integral for parameter going to zero

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to find the limit of an integral of a function for a parameter in that function going to zero.

To be more precise, I am trying to find (EDITED)

$$\lim_{\rho \to 0} \int_0^b ~\Phi \left(\frac {\sqrt{1-\rho} \Phi^{-1}(x) - \Phi^{-1}(c)}{\sqrt \rho} \right)  dx,$$

where $c$ is a constant and $\Phi$ is a standard normal cdf with its inverse $\Phi^{-1}$ , so my integrand is continuous and lies between 0 and 1.

EDITED: Equivalently, the above integral can be expressed as the cdf of a bivariate standard normal distribution defined as follows (not sure this is helpful)

$ \frac 1{2\pi \sqrt{\rho}} \int_{-\infty}^{\Phi^{-1}(b)} \int_{-\infty}^{-\Phi^{-1}(c)} exp\left[ - \frac  {z^2+2 {\sqrt{1-\rho}}  z y + y^2}{2\rho  } \right] ~dz~dy $

Basically, I just need to find some justification to exchange the limit and the integral.

I know that normally, one can move the limit into any function, i.e.

$$\lim_{\rho \to 0} g(f(\rho)) = g(\lim_{\rho \to 0}f(\rho)),$$

when $g(\cdot)$ is not dependent on $\rho$, but I am not sure an integral counts as such a function. I have looked at the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) and the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) but do not believe I can apply them here because I am looking for the limit going to zero.

As an integral can also be understood as a limit of a sum, the key question might be the interchangeability of the limits, as found in a related post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283973/trouble-justifying-moving-the-limit-inside-the-following-integral). However, I am not sure how exactly that applies to my problem!

Comment: 'I know that normally, one can move the limit into any function' not necessarily true. What do you mean by '$f(x, p)$ is a standard normal cdf of a function'?

Comment: Thanks, I explained it more precisely now!

Comment: What is known about $h$? In the current form, it's hard to say what we can do. Perhaps $f(x, \rho)\to g(x)$ uniformly for some $g$? If yes, we can interchange the order of limit and integral.

Comment: I edited again, now the full function is there, including an alternative expression

Comment: DCT is *perfectly* applicable here.

Comment: You can apply the dominated convergence theorem by letting $\rho = \frac 1n$, and taking a limit as $n \to \infty$. In fact, for any positive sequence $a_n \to 0$, you can let $\rho = a_n$ and apply the DCT. It takes some additional argument, though, to get from there to the continuum limit as $\rho \to 0+$.